# OSX Application, get file data that user selected using NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to developing `OSX` Applications. I normally do iOS Apps, so alot of the concepts carry over. However, I cannot quite seem to figure out why I cannot retrieve the data of a file on my system.

Is there something that needs to be done first in order to read files on the users system?

Here is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)btnBrowse:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){

        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            //Get the file url user selected
            NSURL *file = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

            //Get the file data
            NSError *error;
            NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", file] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

            //This returns null
            NSLog(@"%@", fileData);

            //This says that the file does not exist
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSOpenPanel` returns `NSURL` objects, the easiest solution is to use the `NSURL` related API

```
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

If you don't know the text encoding you could use this API, if the reading succeeds, `encoding` contains the used encoding.

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;    
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:file usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that much out, however I am getting a different issue now, that type of file I am trying to open is a `csv`. I get this error: `The file “file.csv” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined.`. Would you be able to help with that?

Comment: Then you have to check other encodings like `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`

Comment: `NSASCIIStringEncoding` was the one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-[NSURL path]` method instead of calling 'file' directly, as it's a NSURL, not NSString.